# How to change format date column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column date transaction (datetrn) with format '20170801' and I want to change in query select become format '01082017'.

If I use function in excel, I just use function like this

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1, 4), MID(A1, 5, 2), RIGHT(A1, 2)).
```

Could you help me how to query in SQL Server? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is a programming help site, but first you need to try to do it yourself, and we'll help you get through that. To learn how to ask good questions you can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This question will most likely be deleted for being too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String manipulations to get it into a `yyyy-mm-dd` format are similar:

```
CAST(
    RIGHT(t.[Date],4) +
    '-' +
    LEFT(RIGHT(t.[Date],4),2) +
    '-' +
    LEFT(t.[Date],2)
AS DATETIME)
```

Here, I assume your table name is `t` and your date column is `Date`.

Comment: It works with little correction "RIGHT(LEFT(t.[Date],6),2)" Thank You

Comment: Oops! I got left and right mixed up. I've fixed it now. Glad i can help

Comment: You can now use the `FORMAT` function for this.

Answer (score 1):

See more [datetime format conversions here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '20170801'

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @dt, 104),'.','')

SELECT FORMAT ( @dt, 'ddMMyyyy')
```

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer - it's much better than the answer that's currently accepted.